# How to get last index of array item using jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I am using below `Array`,

```js
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Badakhshan|Badghis|Baghlan|Balkh|Bamian|Farah|Faryab|Ghazni|Ghowr|Helmand|Herat|Jowzjan|Kabol|Kandahar|Kapisa|Konar|Kondoz|Laghman|Lowgar|Nangarhar|Nimruz|Oruzgan|Paktia|Paktika|Parvan|Samangan|Sar-e Pol|Takhar|Vardak|Zabol";
s_a[2]="Berat|Bulqize|Delvine|Devoll (Bilisht)|Diber (Peshkopi)|Durres|Elbasan|Fier|Gjirokaster|Gramsh|Has (Krume)|Kavaje|Kolonje (Erseke)|Korce|Kruje|Kucove|Kukes|Kurbin|Lezhe|Librazhd|Lushnje|Malesi e Madhe (Koplik)|Mallakaster (Ballsh)|Mat (Burrel)|Mirdite (Rreshen)|Peqin|Permet|Pogradec|Puke|Sarande|Shkoder|Skrapar (Corovode)|Tepelene|Tirane (Tirana)|Tirane (Tirana)|Tropoje (Bajram Curri)|Vlore";
s_a[3]="Adrar|Ain Defla|Ain Temouchent|Alger|Annaba|Batna|Bechar|Bejaia|Biskra|Blida|Bordj Bou Arreridj|Bouira|Boumerdes|Chlef|Constantine|Djelfa|El Bayadh|El Oued|El Tarf|Ghardaia|Guelma|Illizi|Jijel|Khenchela|Laghouat|M'Sila|Mascara|Medea|Mila|Mostaganem|Naama|Oran|Ouargla|Oum el Bouaghi|Relizane|Saida|Setif|Sidi Bel Abbes|Skikda|Souk Ahras|Tamanghasset|Tebessa|Tiaret|Tindouf|Tipaza|Tissemsilt|Tizi Ouzou|Tlemcen";
s_a[4]="Eastern|Manu'a|Rose Island|Swains Island|Western";
s_a[5]="Andorra la Vella|Bengo|Benguela|Bie|Cabinda|Canillo|Cuando Cubango|Cuanza Norte|Cuanza Sul|Cunene|Encamp|Escaldes-Engordany|Huambo|Huila|La Massana|Luanda|Lunda Norte|Lunda Sul|Malanje|Moxico|Namibe|Ordino|Sant Julia de Loria|Uige|Zaire";
s_a[6]="Anguilla";
s_a[7]="Antartica";
.
.
.

s_a[105]="Andhra Pradesh|Arunachal Pradesh|Assam|Bihar|Goa|Gujarat|Haryana|Himachal Pradesh|Jammu and Kashmir|Karnataka|Kerala|Madhya Pradesh|Maharashtra|Manipur|Meghalaya|Mizoram|Nagaland|Orissa|Punjab|Rajasthan|Sikkim|Tamil Nadu|Tripura|Uttar Pradesh|West Bengal|Chhattisgarh|Uttarakhand|Jharkhand|Telangana ";
```

Now, I need to get the index of an item in the last row(s_a[105])
Example:
I have the value 105 in a variable.Then i need index of Assam as 2 .
Please help me...

Comment: `s_a[105].split('|')[2]`

Comment: `array[index].split('|').indexOf(needle)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to combine `split` and `indexOf` methods like

```
index = s_a[variable].split("|").indexOf("Assam");
```

---

Please notice also that it is vanilla JS it does not depend on jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
var vari = s_a[s_a.length-1];
var index = vari.split('|').indexOf('Assam');
```